# How to process multi result set queries with dbExpress

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2007, dbexpress

I have such an sql statement:

```
UPDATE tbworker SET iState=2 WHERE iState=1;
UPDATE tbworker SEt iState=3 WHERE iState=0;
```

And I want to execute this statement in one request to MySQL.

Simple sql requests are excecuted this way:

```
SQLQuery.SQL.Text := SomeSQLText;
AffectedRows := SQLQuery.ExecSQL(true);
```

But now I need a method such as NextResultSet, for example:

```
SQLQuery.SQL.Text := MultyResultSetSQLText;
ResultSetCounter := 1;
AffectedRows.Add(ResultSetCounter, SQLQuery.ExecSQL(true));
while SQLQuery.HasNextResultSets do
begin
  Inc(ResultSetCounter);
  AffectedRows.Add(ResultSetCounter, SQLQuery.GetNextResultSet);
end;
```

How can dbExpress process multy result sets?

Comment: `UPDATE tbworker SET iState = 3 - iState WHERE iState IN (0, 1)`

Comment: But the question was "How to process multi result set queries". Not "how to rewrite two statements in one" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK the [`TSQLDataSet`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SqlExpr_TSQLDataSet.html) and [`TSQLQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery) components can't handle the return of multiple datasets, the only dbexpress component which support [this feature](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/5datasetfetchingmultipleresultsets_xml.html) is the  [TSQLStoredProc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLStoredProc) object.